# Using count in in query with left join

Tags: php, mysql, count, left-join

I am currently trying to count how many dislikes and likes users have given to an image on my website, underneath you will see the database setup I did for exactly that. Vote_type keeps the like and dislike information where 1 is equal to a like, 0 is equal to a dislike.

this table is called projects
[Project table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3Rh.png)

This table is called projects_votes
[image: Vote table]

Now I want to include that when I make a query to drag information from my database for a blog post. This is currently the query I am making to get the necessary information to display a list of blogs on the frontpage. Here I am getting the uploader, project ID for links and so on.

```
    $query = "  
SELECT * FROM projects
LEFT JOIN users
ON fk_usr_id = usr_id
LEFT JOIN projects_maps
ON fk_project_id = project_id    
ORDER BY RAND()
";
```

So what I have a hard time understanding is how to count my Likes and Dislikes on a specific blog, so I can display this information on my website.

Comment: Build a query which shows the `SUM` of column `vote_type` for each project value in your `fk_project_id`.

Comment: "how to count my Likes and Dislikes on a specific blog" What exactly is the input & output? What parts can you do? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @philipxy Hi Philip. I have added the two tables who are to interact with each other.

Comment: I just gave a link to [mre] & I summarized for you right there in the comment & there very clearly still isn't one in your post. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Include everything needed to ask your question in your post. PS Show a try at COUNT().

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by changing my query to this statement here.

```
$query = "  
    SELECT project_id, usr_publicname, project_name, photofile_name, map_version, usr_publicname, map_date, project_id AS project, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM projects_votes WHERE vote_type = 1) AS likes, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM projects_votes WHERE vote_type = 0) AS dislikes FROM projects 

    LEFT JOIN projects_votes ON fk_project_id = project_id 

    LEFT JOIN users ON projects.fk_usr_id = usr_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects_maps ON projects_maps.fk_project_id = projects.project_id
    LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.fk_project_id = projects.project_id

    GROUP BY project_id ORDER BY RAND()
";
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
SELECT project_id,
       sum(case when vote_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) likeCount,
       sum(case when vote_type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) dislikeCount
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN users ON fk_usr_id = usr_id
LEFT JOIN projects_maps ON fk_project_id = project_id   
GROUP BY  project_id
```

Comment: Note that in MySQL, you can omit `case when then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: I think i forgot to include that the table i shared is called projects_votes

Comment: I sovled my problem, I just posted my solution. Perhaps you can check it out, see if you think it is a good solution?